# SQL SERVER Query attribute values from XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have found some similar examples but I have been unable to get it working.

I have inserted the XML data to a table and need an example to query the Param Name and Values where Module Name = "P2"

XML Data looks like this.

```
<TrendProject>
    <Site CncAddress="81" TuaString="T/IQ3 - 00:10:70:00:8B:26/TCP,,,10.17.250.105,10081///13/21/">
        <Lan IsLocal="True" LanNumber="13">
            <Device DeviceNumber="21" VersionString="IQ3xcite128 Iss3.06 Jan 30 2014">
                <DeviceOverview DeviceType="q" MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0" HexEncoded="711B1B1B41333036" Revision="6"></DeviceOverview>
                <Module Name="P1" SubTypeNumber="-1">
                    <Param Name="$" Type="2" Value="Udetemperatur" />
                    <Param Name="S" Type="1" Value="0.0" >
                        <ConEndPoint>S20V</ConEndPoint>
                    </Param>
                    <Param Name="P" Type="6" Value="4" Enum="5 Minutes" />
                    <Param Name="C" Type="6" Value="28732" />
                    <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                    <Param Name="B1" Type="300" >
                        <Param Name="V" Type="1" Value="0.0" />
                        <Param Name="Y" Type="6" Value="2" />
                        <Param Name="S" Type="108" Value="0" />
                        <Param Name="E" Type="6" Value="28732" />
                        <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                        <Param Name="O" Type="6" Value="0" />
                    </Param>
                </Module>
                <Module Name="P2" SubTypeNumber="-1">
                    <Param Name="$" Type="2" Value="BL01 MV 10.X.2 Varme Funktion" />
                    <Param Name="S" Type="1" Value="100.0" >
                        <ConEndPoint>S52V</ConEndPoint>
                    </Param>
                    <Param Name="P" Type="6" Value="4" Enum="5 Minutes" />
                    <Param Name="C" Type="6" Value="57617" />
                    <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                    <Param Name="B1" Type="300" >
                        <Param Name="V" Type="1" Value="100.0" />
                        <Param Name="Y" Type="6" Value="2" />
                        <Param Name="S" Type="108" Value="0" />
                        <Param Name="E" Type="6" Value="57617" />
                        <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                        <Param Name="O" Type="6" Value="0" />
                    </Param>
                </Module>
                <Module Name="P3" SubTypeNumber="-1">
                    <Param Name="$" Type="2" Value="BL01 TF10 Fremlob" />
                    <Param Name="S" Type="1" Value="21.0" >
                        <ConEndPoint>S1V</ConEndPoint>
                    </Param>
                    <Param Name="P" Type="6" Value="4" Enum="5 Minutes" />
                    <Param Name="C" Type="6" Value="57617" />
                    <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                    <Param Name="B1" Type="300" >
                        <Param Name="V" Type="1" Value="21.0" />
                        <Param Name="Y" Type="6" Value="2" />
                        <Param Name="S" Type="108" Value="64" />
                        <Param Name="E" Type="6" Value="57617" />
                        <Param Name="T" Type="7" Value="2014-05-30T09:00:00" />
                        <Param Name="O" Type="6" Value="0" />
                    </Param>
                </Module>
            </Device>
        </Lan>
    </Site>
</TrendProject>
```

I have tried to query the XML in a lot of ways and got stuck. This just returns all attributes for all Modules.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(plotXML XML)

INSERT INTO @myTable(plotXML) Values ((SELECT PlotsSettings From PlotsXMLdata WHERE iqID = 1))

SELECT * FROM @myTable

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT TP2.Param.value('(@Name)', 'nvarchar(4)') as PlotParamName, TP2.Param.value('(@Value)', 'nvarchar(50)') as PlotParamValue, TP.Modules.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as PlotModuleName INTO #Temp
FROM @myTable
CROSS APPLY
plotXML.nodes('/TrendProject/Site/Lan/Device/Module/@Name') as TP(Modules)
CROSS APPLY
plotXML.nodes('(/TrendProject/Site/Lan/Device/Module/Param)') as TP2(Param)

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is in a variable `@xml`

```
 select 
      x.n.value('./@Name','varchar(50)') , 
      x.n.value('./@Value','varchar(50)') 
 from  @xml.nodes('//Module[@Name="P2"]/Param') x(n)
```

or from a table

```
 select 
      x.n.value('./@Name','varchar(50)') , 
      x.n.value('./@Value','varchar(50)') 
 from yourtable
cross apply 
 xmlField.nodes('//Module[@Name="P2"]/Param') x(n)
```

Comment: You saved my day :o) I'm a noop at this and need to order some books on the subject... Thank you.